# abstract class with readonly member

Tags: c#, abstract-class, readonly-attribute

I have a class structure like this where an abstract class A holds an interface IB and a concrete class C in two variables. Which classes get assigned to that interface variable depends on the actual subclass A1, A2 that inherits the abstract class, and need that class C that gets instantiated in the parent class constructor.
So what I came up first was this:

```
abstract class A
{
    protected readonly IB _b;
    protected readonly C _c;

    protected A()
    {
        _c = new C();
    }
}

class B1 : IB
{
   public B1(C c) {}
}

class B2 : IB
{
   public B2(C c) {}
}

class A1 : A
{
    public A1() : base()
    {
        _b = new B1(_c);
    }
}

class A2 : A
{
    public A2() : base()
    {
        _b = new B2(_c);
    }
}
```

The assignment _b = new B1(_c); doesn´t work because its protected.
I also can´t pass the class Bx down to the base constructor, because I need that to be executed before I can instantiate Bx. How else can I achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: `The assignment _b = new B1(_c); doesn't work because its protected` that's not the problem is it - the peoblem is its `readonly` state? Also, isn't the problem that `C` doesnt get instantiated until _after_ `B1`

Comment: no that´s not the issue. Base constructor gets called first, so C is already instantiated when derived constuctor body gets executed. _b = new B1(_c); won´t compile (Error CS0191 A readonly field cannot be assigned to ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_b = ...` doesn't work because readonly fields can only be initialised in the constructor of the class that declares it, not in a subclass. It's not because `_b` is protected. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) says:

> In a field declaration, readonly indicates that assignment to the field can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the **same class**.

One way to work around this is to have the superclass take in a `Func<C, B1>`, and initialise `_b` there.

```
protected A(Func<C, IB> bCreator)
{
    _c = new C();
    _b = bCreator(_c);
}
```

then:

```
class A1 : A
{
    public A1() : base(c => new B1(c))
    {
        
    }
}

class A2 : A
{
    public A2() : base(c => new B2(c))
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `readonly` field can only be instantiated *in the same class*, not in a subclass. Thus, `A`'s constructor needs to set `_b`.

However, you can pass the *knowledge* of how to set `_b` from the subclass to the abstract base class by passing a lambda expression:

Constructor for A:

```
protected A(Func<C, IB> bFactory)
{
    _c = new C();
    _b = bFactory(_c);
}
```

Constructor for A1:

```
public A1() : base(c => new B1(c)) { }
```

Comment: Sweeper´s and your answer are very helpful and almost identical, so I flipped a coin which one to accept.

Comment: @downforme: Sounds fair to me. :-) Glad to be of help!